# Do not close the dialog until the data has passed

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I have a dialog component and another manager component for data handling. My dialog close event send these data to my manager component. How can I send these data without closing dialog.

When manager component got data send to a service and waiting response. I want to create a spinner in the dialog and spin when the service still working and wait the response.

Anyone have a good tip/hint for me? :)
I would be grateful

Dialog component at now (button click action)

```
doAction() {
  this.dialogRef.close({ event: this.action, data: this.form.value });
}
```

Manager component at now

```
openDialog(action, obj) {
  // open dialog    
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  // action handling, send data to CRUD functions
});
```

Comment: You can create a service, and declare a rxjs Subject there. by using it, you can emit values from you dialog component to other components. https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: which type of framework you are using? material or ng-bootstrap?

Comment: I use material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new @output event emitter in the dialog component

```
@Output() dataChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Then use this dataChange to handle the dialog action

```
doAction() {
 this.dataChange.emit(this.form.value);
}
```

In the manager component get the data as follows

```
dialogRef.componentInstance.dataChange.subscribe(result => {
  // action handling, send data to CRUD functions
});
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks. How can I send information to my dialog component that when my service done. I want to create a spinner in dialog component. Example: I need a true value for doAction method, and If it true I close the dialog. When waiting for a value I'll turn on the spinner.